# Walking Neural Networks In Blender?

Tags: physics, external-applications

Is there a way to do [this](https://youtu.be/a3jfyJ9JVeM) in Blender on Windows?

If this specific one isn't a capability, are there other neural net things that I would be able to experiment with in/with Blender?

With that example, I'd like to be able to model ideas I had for new manual wheelchairs, and if the program can learn to use them, then maybe I can have it built in real life.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use neural networks in Blender for instance with Tensorflow and Keras. There are several problems though, while Blender has several ways to simulate physics, it does not have muscle simulation. The interaction between neural network an physics may be very complicated. Adjusting the state based on the output of the neural network will require different adjustments to depending on the physics sim. For some there may not even be a way to adjust parameters mid-way. Interactive display and performance will require that the NN is run in a different process so the UI isn't locked.

It may be technically possible, but as of now this would require extensive work and likely modification of Blender's source.

Comment: I tried doing some simple optimization with tensorflow. But getting feedback from the scene through a `py_function` was not possible? Have you actually tested your answer?

Comment: @Leander I haven't used Tensorflow directly (always through Keras API) or tested this atm. What feedback should or shouldn't be possible? Everything that's accessible from Blender's Python API can be used to read or modify the state.

Comment: Afaik they are the same backend. I couldn't read and write data to the scene from a tensorflow graph. I troed setting bone positions through tensors and reading mesh deformations, but it wouldn't work. Ill try again later. If you could provide a minimal working example, that would be great.

Comment: @Rjg I just saw this example on youtube of tensorflow, thats amazing if it was made with the combination! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmCH-i9Vfw4

Comment: @Leander might not work from within the Tensorflow graph (different process, namespace, interpreter?). It should be possible to use the output of the network, both for calculating the loss and predicting the output after the training is completed. I likely don't have time to do that today, perhaps on the weekend.

Comment: @Starius that's pybullet and Tensorflow. No Blender as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Leander so I've tested it and I get Tensorflow and Keras to run in Blender. The problem is though, that if it needs to be interactive or not lock the UI it would have to be run in a separate process. Multiprocessing is apparently not easy to run in Blender (or not at all from an add-on that imports bpy). The alternative of using subprocess makes serialization a pain, e.g. if you want to evaluate binary/image data.

Comment: I am sure, that Blender is not the rig tool to use for machine learning feedback. But the last sentence of your answer clarifies that already.

Comment: @Leander yes, but since you asked for an MWE I didn't want to let you down without an update. With current situation the best approach is probably subprocess and communication via sockets + (de) serialization. If we ignore the lack of interactive simulations in Blender.

Comment: or pipes of course.